# iOS 5 "Notification Center" API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm talking about this:
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-20120625-233/ios-5-notifications-a-deeper-look/

Those pulldown menus on iOS, I for the love of life cannot find any documentation on how to make a notification so that it shows an update while in another application. I don't know if I just am using the wrong terminology or what, but is it "NSNotificationCenter", and where is any documentation on it?

Thanks :)

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is something completely unrelated.

Comment: UILocalNotification puts a "1" in a red box by my app name, does not flag a banner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numerical badge isn't the only property of a local notification. It can also display banners, and play sounds. These banners are subsequently added to notification center.

Here's an example:

```
- (void)addNotification {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 
    localNotification.fireDate = self.datePicker.date;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.messageField.text;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
 
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;
 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
}
```

And here's a tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Answer (score 2):

refer to [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) by apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

`NSNotificationCenter` is in fact not related and provides API to pass notifications internally in the app itself.